# Перевод объявления для формирования группы на SO

Tags: дефект, локализация

Я заметил что здесь нет переводов некоторых строк:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде здесь таких вопросов еще не было, но могу ошибаться.

Comment: А кнопка "Learn more" так и вовсе ведёт на полностью англоязычный сайт.

Comment: @Yaant это уже другой вопрос) но спасибо за уточнение

Comment: @Yaant судя по всему, оно вообще номинально [не должно было появиться на неанглоязычных SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362267/translation-for-learn-more-not-used-in-so-for-teams#comment1208368_362267). Так что может  свернут эту лавочку для нас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил (и утвердил предложенные) переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/16208
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/10218
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/12459

Для строки "Learn more" существующий перевод не подхватывается. Оформил баг-репорт: [Translation for "Learn more" not used in SO for Teams](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362267/339911)

Строки должны подхватиться в новой сборке. Текущая  rev 2021.3.18.38833

Comment: Спасибо большое :D